# I've got @PO instead of my parameter string in jdbc java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

my code (i have a connection before that):

```
private String loginPasswordRequest = "SELECT * FROM animateurs WHERE email =?";

public static ResultSet SendRequest(String request, String parameter)throws SQLException{
    Connection con = ConnectionToDatabase();
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(request);
    stmt.setString(1, "jdupont@sonmail.fr"); //parameter

    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
    return result;
}
```

when i execute the request i have the following request :

```
SELECT * FROM animateurs WHERE email =@PO
```

this is the request executed by SQLServer
i don't know why my parameter doesn't appear. I just need to create a select with one parameter but it doesn't work.

Comment: You're leaking a `Statement` and a `Connection` to return a `ResultSet` there, are you sure that doesn't indicate a placeholder? Is there a record in the `animateurs` table where the `email` matches your parameter? Does the query work from query manager?

Comment: i've got one result on Sql Server Managment Studio. The problem is the parameter @PO is executed instead of my actual parameter rigth before being interpreted

Comment: Define "doesn't work": do you get an exception (if so, what exception), do you get an empty result, or something else? It looks like the SQL Server driver does some preprocessing, replacing positional parameters with named parameters (ie using `@P0` for the first positional parameter). My expectation is that this works (apart from the fact that you are leaking resources here), because SQL Server will send the parameter values separately.

Comment: I don't get any exceptions, i've got an empty ResultSet

Answer (score 0):

i found it, the result wasn't empty at all. i needed to make a while on result.next even if i have one result in my Result Set

Comment: I strongly suggest that you follow some tutorials on JDBC and read the API documentation, because having to call `next()` on a result set (always) is really the basics of JDBC.